# I have been adding an event Listener to this button and getting an error. What I'm I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have been trying to add an event listener to this button and getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

```js
let button = document.getElementById('submit');

function hello() {
    
 console.log("hello");
}

button.addEventListener('click', hello);
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because the js loads before the html.
Try to put your js code into this function:

```
window.onload = () => {
    \\ your js code
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was putting my script tag in the header so you are right my js was loading before my html. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The code seems fine and actually is working!

However, this problem usually happens when you forget, or  mistype the id/class of the element. So when the script try to listen the event, he is unable to find the element.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I just had my script tag in the wrong spot :)